# How to create multi-row table?

Tags: tables, multirow

I want to draw the following table :

[image]

I have used the following latex code to do the above table :

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline 
{\bf  Prefix} & {\bf  Type } & {\bf  No of digits} & {\bf  2nd  digits} & {\bf  Text number} & {\bf   Text-number} & {\bf  Text digit} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{12-14}} & Text-MCCC\\ \cline{3-3}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Text-VSSS \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces :

[image]

Anyone can tell me how can I draw my desired table. Thanks

Comment: Don't use `\bf` .. it's deprecated. Use `\textbf{...}` or (since it's inside a tabular cell) `\bfseries`

Comment: I am not sure you need `\multicolumn` at all

Comment: You don't have any cells spanning more than 1 column in your sample image.

Comment: What cells/columns should appear as paragraphs is not clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

This should let you start. The missing rows are left as an exercise for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[left=.45in,right=.45in,top=.6in,bottom=.6in,headheight=14.5pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % for \ordinalnum
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|C{1.2cm}|C{1.2cm}|c|c|C{1.2cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Prefix} & \textbf{Type} & \textbf{No of digits} & \textbf{\ordinalnum{2} digits} 
  & \textbf{Text number} & \textbf{Text-number} & \textbf{Text digit} \\ 
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{12-14} & \multirow{4}{*}{Text-MCCC} & \multirow{4}{*}{16} & 1 
  & \ordinalnum{2}-\ordinalnum{3} & \multirow{4}{*}{Long text here} & \multirow{4}{1.2cm}{\centering Text with digits}\\ 
\cline{4-5}
& & & 2 & \ordinalnum{2}-\ordinalnum{4} & & \\
\cline{4-5}
& & & 3 & \ordinalnum{2}-\ordinalnum{5} & & \\
\cline{4-5}
& & & 4 & \ordinalnum{2}-\ordinalnum{6} & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I really think that creating such tables is much easier in ConTeXt than in LaTeX. For example, this is how you can create such a table using Natural Tables (which work quite similar to HTML tables). Note that the syntax is readable and there is clean separation of content and presentation.

```
\startsetups table:style
  \setupTABLE[row][1][style=bold]
  \setupTABLE[each][each][align={middle,lohi}, offset=0.5em]
  \setupTABLE[column][last][width=1.5cm]
\stopsetups
\starttext

\bTABLE[setups={table:style}]
  \bTR
    \bTD Prefix \eTD
    \bTD Type   \eTD
    \bTD No of \\ digits \eTD
    \bTD 2nd \\ digits   \eTD
    \bTD Text number     \eTD
    \bTD Text-number     \eTD
    \bTD Text \\ digit   \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD[nr=4] 12-14     \eTD
    \bTD[nr=4] Text-MCCC \eTD
    \bTD[nr=4] 16        \eTD
    \bTD 1               \eTD
    \bTD 2nd--3rd        \eTD
    \bTD[nr=4] Long text here \eTD
    \bTD[nr=4] Text with digits \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD 2        \eTD
    \bTD 2nd--4th \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD 3        \eTD
    \bTD 2nd--5th \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD 4        \eTD
    \bTD 2nd--6th \eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD[nr=2]  4        \eTD
    \bTD[nr=2] Text-VSSS \eTD
    \bTD 13              \eTD
    \bTD --              \eTD
    \bTD[nr=2] 2nd--6th  \eTD
    \bTD 7th--12th       \eTD
    \bTD Text with digits\eTD
  \eTR
  \bTR
    \bTD 16         \eTD
    \bTD --         \eTD
    \bTD 7th--15th  \eTD
    \bTD Text with digits \eTD
  \eTR
\eTABLE

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]